# ajax request on 'onChange' or 'onClick' of an input

Tags: reactjs

My react element looks like so:

```js
var superagent = require('superagent')

var app = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            message: '',
            dataList: []
        }
    },

    search (event) {
        var component = this;
        superagent.request('someurl?search=' + event.target.value)
            .end(function(err, res){
                component.setState({ dataList: res });
            })
    },

    render() {
        return <input type="text" value={this.state.message} onChange={this.search} />
    }
})
```

On the moment I type in the search bar starts to get laggy and I get this message in the console over 20K times.

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

Even If I seperate the two functions and the ajax request is only made when I click on a button and the text itself updates itself from another function that is responsible to updates the text it still gets laggy. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**
the real entire component as you asked:

```
            var ami = new require('asterisk-manager')('0000','0.0.0.1','xxxx','xxxx', true); 
            var ipc = require('ipc');
            var request = require('request');
            ipc.on("update-status", function (name, status) {
                //console.log(name, status);
            });
            var Extension = React.createClass({
                getInitialState () {    
                    return {
                        statusText: '',
                        circleColor: '#00FF00'
                    }
                },
                setStatus (status) {
                    if(status == 1) {
                        this.setState({statusText: 'Busy', circleColor: 'red'});
                    } else if(status == 8) {
                        this.setState({statusText: 'Dialing', circleColor: '#0099FF'});
                    } else {
                        this.setState({statusText: 'Available', circleColor: '#00FF00'});
                    }
                },
                call () {
                    if(typeof this.props.extension == 'undefined') {
                        this.props.callback(this.props.client.phone);
                    } else {
                        this.props.callback(this.props.extension);
                    }
                    console.log('Calling: ' + this.props.extension.name);
                },
                render: function() {
                    var component = this;
                    setInterval(function(){
                        ami.action({
                          'action': 'ExtensionState',
                          'exten': component.props.extension.name,
                          'context': 'default'
                        }, function(err, res) {
                            if(component.props.extension.name == res.exten)
                            component.setStatus(res.status);
                        });
                    }, 2000)
                    if(typeof this.props.extension == 'undefined') {
                        return (
                            <li>
                                <div id="wrapperDiv">
                                    <img src="assets/images/anon_user.png" width="50" />
                                    <div id="circle" style={{background: this.state.circleColor}}></div>
                                </div>
                                <span>{this.props.client.name}</span><br />
                                <span>{this.props.client.phone}</span>
                                <a onClick={this.call}>Click To Call</a>
                            </li>
                        )
                    } else {
                        return (
                            <li>
                                <div id="wrapperDiv">
                                    <img src="assets/images/anon_user.png" width="50" />
                                    <div id="circle" style={{background: this.state.circleColor}}></div>
                                </div>
                                <span>{this.props.extension.name}({this.state.statusText})</span>
                                <a onClick={this.call}>Click To Call</a>
                            </li>
                        )
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Something is missing here. You set `dataList` in the component's state, but you never use it anywhere. Did you leave something out?

Comment: This is just an example of how my actual component looks like. My real component has alot more code in It. Just wanted to keep things simple.

Comment: It's good that you want to keep things simple but you left out the relevant part, that mounts the component. Something like this: 
React.render(<app />,document.getElementById('container'));

Answer (score 0):

Its important to remember that the `render` method is going to be called every time you setState. In this case you've implemented a setInterval method within your `render` method, and you aren't ever clearing that interval (`clearInterval`). So each time you render, a new setInterval timer is being created, which executes ami.action, which sets state, which re-renders, which sets up another interval. My guess is that's where your lag comes from.

If you are looking to capture the value from an input field, I'd recommend using a lifecycle method like `componentWillUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate` depending on your use case.

If you are trying to capture data that is changing from the server on a timely basis, you should use `componentWillMount` to setup the interval, and handle it with your existing `setStatus` method. Just be sure to clear the interval during the `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method.

Relavant resource: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html